# What is the main advantage of using prototype in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
function Candy(name) {
 this.name = name;
}
Candy.prototype.printName = function () {
 console.log(this.name);
}
var chocolate = new Candy("chocolate");
chocolate.printName();
var gummyBears = new Candy("gummy bears");
gummyBears.printName();
```

This does exactly the same thing as not using the prototype:

```
function Candy(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.printName = function () {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}
var chocolate = new Candy("chocolate");
chocolate.printName();
var gummyBears = new Candy("gummy bears");
gummyBears.printName();
```

So I’m not sure what the advantage of using a prototype instead is either!

Comment: Using prototype enables inheritance or mixin pattern.

Comment: I recommend you reading about [Object.prototypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes) and [Lookup Mechanisms](https://www.d.umn.edu/~gshute/asm/objects/objects.xhtml)

Comment: "This does exactly the same thing as not using the prototype" - this is not so. While on the surface it seems so in this contrived example, every instance of `Candy` in your second example has it's own `printName` function, whereas in the first example there is only _one_ `printName` function, and all instances can access it through the prototype chain.

Answer (score 3):

Here I am trying to give you an example to show you the advantage of prototype in JavaScript.

## ex: Classes

Classes, Prototypes, Object Oriented JavaScript is a paradigm for structuring our complex code.

> In JavaScript we use  **Prototype chain**, a feature under the hood that enables emulation of OOP and which is a compelling tool in itself.
>
> In new versions of javascript we use the `new` and `class` keywords  to automate our object & method creation.

We use objects to represent real objects with their data and their functionalities. There is mainly 04 way to do so:

### 1. Each **object** store its own functions with its associated data.

This is the trivial and the easy solution, but its cons imagine we have two objects with same functionality => Whenever we create a new object we allocate space in the memory for all our data and functions while those functions are the same! Bad approach. That is why the second approach comes: **Prototype chain**; why we use prototypes".

### 2. Use the **prototype chain**:

check the code below:

```js
function userCreator (name, score) {
 const newUser = Object.create(userFunctionStore); // to link to the the new created object to its functionalities
 newUser.name = name;
 newUser.score = score;
 return newUser;
};
const userFunctionStore = {
 increment: function(){this.score++;},
 login: function(){console.log("Logged in");}
 ...
};
const user1 = userCreator("user1", 3);
const user2 = userCreator("user2", 5);
user1.increment();
```

We Store the common function `increment` in just one object. So whence the new created user does not find the finction in its own object it will look via its generated link by  `Object.create()` to `functionStore` and here it can get the function it looks for `increment`.

> Note: All objects have a `__proto__` property whcih by default links to a big object `Object.prototype` which have useful functions; like `e hasOwnProperty` method that check if an object has the given property; that we can access to it here via `userFunctionStore`’s `__proto__` property.

#### Conclusion

Good approach but quite long and not standard.

### 3. Use `new` keyword to automates the hard work.

Look at the code below

```js
function userCreator(name, score) {
    const newUser = Object.create(functionStore);
    newUser this.name = name;
    newUser this.score = score;
    return newUser;
   };
   functionStore userCreator.prototype // {};
   functionStore userCreator.prototype.increment = function(){
    this.score++;
   }
   const user1 = userCreator("user1", 3);
```

With the used of `new` keyword it will be resumed to

```js
function userCreator(name, score) {
    this.name = name;
    this.score = score;
};
userCreator.prototype // {};
userCreator.prototype.increment = function(){
    this.score++;
}
const user1 = new userCreator("user1", 3);
```

So automatically `new` will do 03 main things:

1. `this: {}` => Create automatically `this` empty object to assign the properties and values to it.
2. `__proto: userCreator.prototype` => Add `__proto__` hidden property to `this` new created object and link it to `userCreator.prototype` that is an object that store the common functions.
3. `return this` => **return** `this` new created object.

Look at this code:

```js
function userCreator(name, score){
    this.name = name;
    this.score = score;
}
userCreator.prototype.increment = function(){ this.score++; };
userCreator.prototype.login = function(){ console.log("login"); };
const user1 = new userCreator("user1", 3)
user1.increment()
```

Here is a simulation of the explanation above.

```json
user1 = {
  name: 'user1',
  score: 3,
  __proto__: userCreator.prototype
}

userCreator = function + prototype =>

prototype = {
    increment: function(){ this.score++; },
    login: function(){ console.log("login"); }
}
```

#### Conclusion

Faster to write. Often used in practice in professional code. A Lot of developers do not know how it works. We have to upper case first letter of the function, so we know it requires `new` to work!

### 4. The class "syntactic sugar"

Write our shared (common) methods in the object creator itself. The code should be:

```js
class UserCreator {
 constructor (name, score){
 this.name = name;
 this.score = score;
 }
 increment (){ this.score++; }
 login (){ console.log("login"); }
}
const user1 = new UserCreator("user1", 3);
user1.increment();
```

#### Conclusion

This approach is emerging as a new standard, and feels more like style of other languages (e.g. Python)

> Very important this `class` keyword is just comes to remove the confusion using `new`keywords but under the hoods it is absolutly working as same `new` key word. So do not get confused by other languages.

### Reference

All credits go for this course [JavaScript: The Hard Parts, v2](https://frontendmasters.com/courses/javascript-hard-parts-v2/).